# How do I write data to disk in UTF-8 encoding in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

The following Python code ...

```
html_data = urllib2.urlopen(some_url).read()
f = codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(html_data)
f.close()
```

... sometimes fails with `UnicodeDecodeError` ...

```
File "/.../lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 686, in write
  return self.writer.write(data)
File "/.../lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 351, in write
  data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 5605: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My questions:

- How do I make sure my `urllib2.urlopen(some_url).read()` call always returns UTF-8?
- Is there anything wrong with my `codecs.open(...)` call that prevents it from storing my data to disk in UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AFAIK, You cannot do that. However, You can detect encoding from headers / html and re-encode.
2. I don't know. I have always used binary mode for writing and it always worked

Example:

```
data = urlopen(uri).read().decode(encoding)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `codecs.open` -- it's with passing to `.write` a byte string that (given the `\xd0` code in it) is clearly encoded in some `ISO-8859-*` or related codec.

[urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2.urlopen#urllib2.urlopen) returns a response object which, besides file-like behavior, as the extra method:

> `info()` — return the meta-information
>   of the page, such as headers, in the
>   form of an `httplib.HTTPMessage`
>   instance (see [Quick Reference to HTTP
>   Headers](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/http.html))

In particular the `Content-Type` header, for text-like contents, should have a `charset` parameter specifying the encoding it uses, e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4`.  You need to parse and isolate the `charset` and use it to decode the contents into Unicode (so your `codecs.open`ed file-like object always gets unicode arguments to `write` and properly writes them out in `utf-8`).

If `charset` is missing, or using it to decode the text results in errors (suggesting `charset` is wrong), as the last hope of salvation you can try the [Universal Encoding Detector](http://chardet.feedparser.org/) which uses heuristics for the purpose (after all, many pages on the web have horrible metadata errors, as well as broken HTML and so forth).

Comment: Technically, the default charset for HTML is "iso-8859-1", so if there is no charset declared, it should be iso-8859-1.  Of course, HTML is a wild and wooly world, so there's no guarantee that a document served with no charset is actually in iso-8859-1.

Comment: @Ned, good point, but I'd _still_ try the UED just in case (of course it can't distinguish between the various ISO-8859-etc classes or cognates like CP1252, but at least it's a "plan B" for safety;-).